# Ruby errors with OS X Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-yosemite

I just upgraded to OS X Yosemite and am running into all sorts of issues running my Rails app.  I'm constantly seeing the following error:

```
ruby(11958,0x7fff7e430300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f880b801808: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Abort trap: 6
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

**Edit**

I tried following the suggestions on this page:

[How to get Ruby / Homebrew / RVM to work on Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225959/how-to-get-ruby-homebrew-rvm-to-work-on-yosemite?rq=1)

But when I edit brew.rb to change the path to "Current," I get the error:

```
Homebrew requires Leopard or higher. For Tiger support, see:
https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew
```

**Solution**

I completely removed rvm and reinstalled from scratch.  In order to remove rvm, I first had to run

```
rvm fix-permissions
```

then

```
rvm implode
```

I then followed the directions on this page:

https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite

Comment: Does the ruby process exit?  Does apple's crash reporter launch?

Comment: @JaredBeck yes ruby process exits, but apple doesn't launch a crash report.

Comment: @sylar I've updated xcode and the command line tools.

Comment: @scientiffic what are you doing to generate that error?

Comment: @sylar almost any rails command.  for example, 'rails s' gives me that error.

Comment: @scientiffic I would uninstall every ruby and rails then reinstall them. I would also do a gem update --system. But it's weird as I've upgraded with no issues with any ruby or rails on my MBP.

Comment: You should be able to write an Answer, instead of editing your own question with a solution.  Something to try in the future, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

rbenv is pretty good too. I've been using it since my first ruby/rails days without an error.

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv