# Ruby malloc error: incorrect checksum for freed object in Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I am trying to start my rails server project. But it just brings me this error  "Ruby malloc error: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed". I have tried to find solution by googling and practicing with their answers. It seems not help.

[image]

Note: I use ruby version 2.1.2 with Xcode version 7.1 and Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.

Comment: If you use `rvm` and recently upgraded, try `rvm implode` and starting over. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478906/ruby-errors-with-os-x-yosemite

Comment: Is it the problem of rvm since I upgrade the OS? So that mean I have to install rbenv for this moment?

Comment: You can continue using `rvm`, just try reinstalling it and Ruby.

Comment: I have tried this. it doesn't work