# Get latest Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, rvm, homebrew

I'm currently running into some problems when trying to install the latest Ruby version using RVM. I receive the following error when using `rvm install ruby-2.2.0`

```
user$ rvm install ruby-2.2.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.2.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
ERROR: '/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it!
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I then run `brew doctor` and get the following error

```
 /usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
 /usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

RVM gets stable commanded presented to me with this warning and I still never got the stable version

```
* WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
to do that add the following line to '/Users/user/.bash_profile':

  source ~/.profile
```

How can I fix this? I've been avoiding it for a while and really want to get it up and running. Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24225960/429758

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to do:

```
cd /usr/local/Library
git pull origin master
```

This will upgrade your homebrew and you can use brew again.

If you has problems with Permissions, try:

```
sudo git pull origin master
```

For Yosemite try this:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions
sudo ln -s Current 1.8
brew update
sudo rm 1.8
```

For OS X 10.8.3 Try this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local
cd /usr/local
git reset --hard origin/master
brew update
```

Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) no longer ships with Ruby 1.8 (only 2.0)
Update brew with git:

```
cd /usr/local/Library/
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
# on branch master
git pull
```

For the second question, edit `/Users/user/.bash_profile`, then add the next sentence:

```
source ~/.profile
```