# Rails 4.1 Unable to install Elasticsearch on Mac OS X Yosemite using Homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, elasticsearch, homebrew

Want to use Elasticsearch so I can use the Searchkick gem for my app. Installed the latest version of java on firefox. installed the Searchkick gem. but when I type brew install elasticsearch get and error message

```
 /usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
    /usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

Have Homebrew installed , to check i ran ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" and got

```
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
```

It there way to fix this or do i have to download the Elasticsearch file and install it manually?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225959/how-to-get-ruby-homebrew-rvm-to-work-on-yosemite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to be a problem with homebrew and yosemite. maybe this can help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153790/how-to-fix-brew-after-its-upgrade-to-yosemite