# Ruby / Brew Stopped Working Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I'm fairly new to this so hang with me..

I have been searching for a solution to this problem for a week now.

Ruby does not seem to be working

```
ruby
-bash: ruby: command not found
```

or

```
ruby -v
-bash: ruby: command not found
```

and whenever I try homebrew this is what comes back

```
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:     /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: bad     interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

as you can see above I had changed the ruby framework to read from 1.8 to Current as others had suggested, however this did not solve the problem as it did for users who had encountered the same issue.

So the search continues on...

My usr/local/bin/brew script looks like this -

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0
# encoding: UTF-8

std_trap = trap("INT") { exit! 130 } # no backtrace thanks

HOMEBREW_BREW_FILE = ENV['HOMEBREW_BREW_FILE']

if ARGV == %w{--prefix}
  puts File.dirname(File.dirname(HOMEBREW_BREW_FILE))
  exit 0
end

require 'pathname'
HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH =     Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath.dirname.parent.join("Library/Homebrew").to_s
$:.unshift(HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH + '/vendor')
$:.unshift(HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH)
require 'global'

case ARGV.first when '-h', '--help', '--usage', '-?', 'help', nil
  require 'cmd/help'
  puts Homebrew.help_s
  exit ARGV.first ? 0 : 1
when '--version'
  puts HOMEBREW_VERSION
  exit 0
when '-v'
  puts "Homebrew #{HOMEBREW_VERSION}"
  # Shift the -v to the end of the parameter list
  ARGV << ARGV.shift
  # If no other arguments, just quit here.
  exit 0 if ARGV.length == 1
end

   # Check for bad xcode-select before anything else, because `doctor` and
# many other things will hang
# Note that this bug was fixed in 10.9
if OS.mac? && `xcode-select -print-path 2>/dev/null`.chomp == '/' &&     MacOS.version < :mavericks
  ofail <<-EOS.undent
  Your xcode-select path is currently set to '/'.
  This causes the `xcrun` tool to hang, and can render Homebrew unusable.
  If you are using Xcode, you should:
    sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
  Otherwise, you should:
    sudo rm -rf /usr/share/xcode-select
 EOS

  exit 1
end

case HOMEBREW_PREFIX.to_s when '/', '/usr'
  # it may work, but I only see pain this route and don't want to support it
  abort "Cowardly refusing to continue at this prefix: #{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}"
end
if OS.mac? and MacOS.version < "10.5"
  abort <<-EOABORT.undent
    Homebrew requires Leopard or higher. For Tiger support, see:
    https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew
  EOABORT
end

# Many Pathname operations use getwd when they shouldn't, and then throw
# odd exceptions. Reduce our support burden by showing a user-friendly error.
Dir.getwd rescue abort "The current working directory doesn't exist, cannot proceed."


def require? path
  require path.to_s.chomp
rescue LoadError => e
  # HACK :( because we should raise on syntax errors but
  # not if the file doesn't exist. TODO make robust!
  raise unless e.to_s.include? path
end

begin
  trap("INT", std_trap) # restore default CTRL-C handler

  aliases = {'ls' => 'list',
             'homepage' => 'home',
             '-S' => 'search',
             'up' => 'update',
             'ln' => 'link',
             'instal' => 'install', # gem does the same
             'rm' => 'uninstall',
             'remove' => 'uninstall',
             'configure' => 'diy',
             'abv' => 'info',
             'dr' => 'doctor',
             '--repo' => '--repository',
             'environment' => '--env',
             '-c1' => '--config',
             }

  cmd = ARGV.shift
  cmd = aliases[cmd] if aliases[cmd]

  sudo_check = Set.new %w[ install link pin unpin upgrade ]

  if sudo_check.include? cmd
    if Process.uid.zero? and not File.stat(HOMEBREW_BREW_FILE).uid.zero?
      raise "Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew #{cmd}`\n#{SUDO_BAD_ERRMSG}"
    end
  end

  # Add contributed commands to PATH before checking.
  ENV['PATH'] += ":#{HOMEBREW_CONTRIB}/cmd"
  if require? HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY/"Library/Homebrew/cmd"/cmd
    Homebrew.send cmd.to_s.gsub('-', '_').downcase
  elsif which "brew-#{cmd}"
    %w[CACHE CELLAR LIBRARY_PATH PREFIX REPOSITORY].each do |e|
      ENV["HOMEBREW_#{e}"] = Object.const_get "HOMEBREW_#{e}"
    end
    exec "brew-#{cmd}", *ARGV
  elsif require? which("brew-#{cmd}.rb").to_s
    exit 0
  else
    onoe "Unknown command: #{cmd}"
    exit 1
  end

rescue FormulaUnspecifiedError
  abort "This command requires a formula argument"
rescue KegUnspecifiedError
  abort "This command requires a keg argument"
rescue UsageError
  onoe "Invalid usage"
  abort ARGV.usage
rescue SystemExit
  puts "Kernel.exit" if ARGV.verbose?
  raise
rescue Interrupt => e
  puts # seemingly a newline is typical
  exit 130
rescue BuildError => e
  e.dump
  exit 1
rescue RuntimeError, SystemCallError => e
  raise if e.message.empty?
  onoe e
  puts e.backtrace if ARGV.debug?
  exit 1
rescue Exception => e
  onoe e
  puts "#{Tty.white}Please report this bug:"
  puts "    #{Tty.em}#{ISSUES_URL}#{Tty.reset}"
  puts e.backtrace
  exit 1
else
  exit 1 if Homebrew.failed?
end

    enter code here
```

Does any of this make sense or ring any bells?
Could it have anything to do with why I'm getting the Homebrew or Ruby error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'd be happy to provide as much information as possible for us to solve this problem! :)

EDIT:

This is what happens when I try to run brew doctor:

```
rvm install ruby
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file     https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-    2.2.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:     /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: bad     interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
ERROR: '/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew  doctor' to fix it!
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
$ brew doctor
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:     /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Ruby / Homebrew / RVM to work on Yosemite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225959/how-to-get-ruby-homebrew-rvm-to-work-on-yosemite)

Comment: I used that post in order to change the version from 1.8 to Current as suggested however it did not work as i am still encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't run `echo "puts 'hello world'" |  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby`  at a terminal prompt, something has happened that has uninstalled your system Ruby and you should reinstall OS X to restore it.